# CSS 3 checkbox value is null when set to "off"

Tags: html, css

I have the following checkbox:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="showOnNavigation" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="showOnNavigation" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="showOnNavigation">
    <div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
    <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

The CSS for it:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
    width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #A3D900; color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #333333;
    text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
    width: 25px; margin: 2.5px;
    background: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 56px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

When I'm submitting a form and checkbox is on the ON position, the checkbox value is ON. When it is on OFF position, the value is not set to OFF, so my script will issue an error that the index is not set. It used to work before, but for some reason it doesn't work anymore. Really frustrating, kindly HELP!! A CSS only approach would be most preffered, otherwsie I could easily do this with JavaScript.

I got the code generated from http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a hidden field with the same name before your checkbox with a value of "OFF"

Comment: Why would I want do that? `.onoffswitch-inner:before` and `.onoffswitch-inner:after` are responsible for setting the values ON or off

Comment: If a checkbox is not checked, it doesn't actually send a value with the form. By putting a hidden field before the checkbox with the same name, but a different value, their will always be a value associated with that parameter. If the checkbox is not checked, the browser will send the value from the hidden field, if it is checked, the checkbox will overwrite the value set in the hidden field, and the browser will send the value of the checkbox.

Comment: The .onoffswitch-inner:before and :after are just styling the "ON" and "OFF" text of the switch. It's not actually doing anything with the value of your checkbox.

Comment: Very embarrased for such a noob mistake! Thank you very much!!